# Proper handle of python decorators and kwargs

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a flask application with a decorator I made to handle some values. For the purpose of this question I will keep it simple:

```
def decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated function(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['test_value'] = 15
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

This decorator is right after the request, like:

```
@app.route('/a/<path>/with/<these>')
@decorator
def function_flask(path, these):
    print(path, these)
    return 1
```

However, I get an error that function_flask got an unexpected keyword argument 'test_value'. Now obviously, somehow, kwargs 'test_value' is passed to the function_flask. But why?

Am I improperly handling kwargs?

Comment: because you return `f(*args, **kwargs)` and thus include the kwargs. If you want to add kwargs in your decorator you need to handle them in your function.

Comment: @JakobF Yes, and I need them for other functions. However for this one I do not want them to get consumed by function_flask. Is there any way I can avoid this? Make the function_flask ignore the kwargs? I am really confused on the concept. Thank you!

Comment: you could just add `**kwargs` as a third parameter of `function_flask` which will then quietly take all kwargs.

Comment: That will work, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add *`*kwargs` as the third parameter of `function_flask`.